# Which is the best way for performance in Python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, filter, list-comprehension

Here is a members list and each member has a group name and a member name.

```
members = [
    {"group": "python", "name": "best"},
    ....
]
```

When new member is added, I would like to check that it is unique or not.

Simply, I could check using for loop.

```
for member in members:
    if member["group"] == group and member["name"]:
        !!! exist !!!
```

Moreover, there are many ways to check.

```
if any([member["group"] == group and member["name"] == name for member in members]):
if [member for member in members if member["group"] == group and member["name"] == name]:
if filter(lambda member: member["group"] == group and member["name"] == name, members):
```

I hate to make code lines more, so, I would like to not use the first example (for loop).

Whenever I concentrate on the issue, I search and think again.
But, I would like to make a final decision for this issue.

Please give me your thought.

Comment: Using a *set of tuples* instead of a list of dicts would solve this problem by itself: `{('Python', 'best'), …}`.

Comment: Don't do `any([x for x ...])` but directly `any(x for x ...)` that avoid buildint the whole list comprehension, it'll stop when one is True

Comment: @deceze, Thank you for comment! I have never thought using a set of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If we were going to be very nit-picky we could order all of the entries by alphabetical order, then do a binary search on all the entries.
However, I think for this small case, a linear approach is more than file. And would have little to know impact on performance on a small scale.

If you wanted to check that a certain value wasn't repeated. E.G. no 2 entries can both have 'group' == 'python', but you didn't care about the rest of the data being the same.
Then an approach like this would work:

```
members = [{"group": "python", "name": "best"}, {"group": "cpp", "name": "worst"}]
group_to_look_for = 'python'
if len(list(filter(lambda x : x == group_to_look_for, (i['group'] for i in members)))) == 0:
    # Do stuff :)
```

This code, gets all of the groups from the members list, and then filters out all the entries which don't have a 'group' of 'python'.

If you wanted uniqueness on all of the data in each dictionary, then an approach like this would work:

```
members = [{"group": "python", "name": "best"}, {"group": "cpp", "name": "worst"}]
data_to_look_for = {"group": "python", "name": "best"}

if data_to_look_for not in members:
    # Do stuff :)
```

I'm not sure about the efficiency of both these methods, but I would say they'd be pretty fast because they use built-ins.

I hope this helped and if you have any questions feel free to ask